# Open current file in web browser in Vim

Tags: vim

I'd like to be able to send the HTML file I'm currently editing in `vim` to my web browser, Chrome. I'm running Linux.

This gets me very close:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>w :!google-chrome % &
```

The browser opens and displays the correct file. However, the command isn't running in the background, which is what the `&` is supposed to do. Instead `vim` drops to the background and I get some text output to my terminal window. I then have to do some clicking and `Enter` pressing to get my `vim` to come back to the foreground.

Am I missing something?

UPDATE: Thanks for all the suggestions. The issue seems to be that the focus seems to shift away from my terminal window when the browser window opens. Not sure if there's anything I can do about this.

Comment: Found this useful ( kind of a RTFM answer): [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preview_current_HTML_file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preview_current_HTML_file)

Answer (score 9):

From my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F12>f :exe ':silent !firefox %'<CR>
nnoremap <F12>c :exe ':silent !chromium-browser %'<CR>
nnoremap <F12>o :exe ':silent !opera %'<CR>
```

These three commands open the current file in the chosen browser without side effects. The use of `<F12>` makes it GVim-only, though.

Comment: How about using `sensible-browser` to open the default browser?

Comment: on OS X, I've noticed that `!open %` seems to work well, and `!open '%'` slightly better for files that contain non- `\'` metacharacters

Comment: If Chrome or Firefox is not started yet, this causes Vim or Neovim to get stuck until you close the browser.

Answer (score 5):

For Mac, you might have to type something that looks more like this:

```
nnoremap <F12>f :exe ':silent !open -a /Applications/Firefox.app %'<CR>
nnoremap <F12>c :exe ':silent !open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %'<CR>
nnoremap <F12>g :exe ':silent !open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %'<CR>
nnoremap <F12>s :exe ':silent !open /Applications/Safari.app %'<CR>
```

Notce it's **Safari.app** on the end...it'll save you a few minutes. :)

Answer (score 4):

What about `:!open % -a Google\ Chrome` ?

Comment: This just ask Vim to run a terminal command, not sure if it's possible to find a reference in the help file.

Comment: `help !` and `help %`

Comment: Actually I'm confused by this name format 'Google\ Chrome'. But I found it's really named like this '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/'.

Answer (score 3):

You can `exec` chrome `silent`ly:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>w :exec 'silent !google-chrome % &'
```

---

`:exe[cute] {expr1} ..` Executes the string that results from the evaluation of {expr1} as an Ex command.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting a similar result. It's writing to standard output, `Created new window in existing browser session.` I tried redirecting the output to `/dev/null`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Grrr. Same result. `vim` has a lot of ways of doing the same thing. :)

Answer (score 3):

I use the `shell.vim` plugin to run commands in background on Windows.  I don't know exactly what it does, but I believe it also works for that on Linux:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3123

Shell.vim does allow for asynchronous external commands, but I don't know whether it allows you to keep focus with Vim terminal, avoid moving back manually.

Another plugin that allows asynchronous calls is below, although it relies on having Vim compiled with Python support and I haven't tested:
https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-background-cmd

Answer (score 3):

For windows7 x64,
 - F2 to open current file,
 - F3 to lookup current cword under cursor.

```
for g:chrome_exe in [
    \'C:\Progra~2\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
    \'C:\Progra~1\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
    \'C:\Progra~1\Google\Chrome\Applic~1\chrome.exe',
    \'C:\Users\'.$USERNAME.'\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' 
    \]
    if !filereadable(g:chrome_exe)
        continue
    endif
    let g:google_url='https://www.google.com/search?oq=&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=0&q='
    :nmap   <F2> :exe ":!start ".g:chrome_exe." --user-data-dir=%TEMP%/chrome-vim-sandbox file:///".expand("%:p")<CR>
    :nmap   <F3> :exe ":!start ".g:chrome_exe." --user-data-dir=%TEMP%/chrome-vim-sandbox ".g:google_url.expand("<cword>")<CR>
    break
endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [small plugin](https://github.com/countoren/WSearch) with 7 commands to handle web searches.

After installing you could use:

- `:WSearchInit` to start a sites repository in the current folder
- `:WSearchSaveTagAndSite google www.google.com/search?q={WSearch}` to save a site with corresponding tag

and then search with:

- `:WSearch` will run your latest saved or searched site replacing `{WSearch}` with the cursored word
- `:WSearch Manual Search` will do the same as `WSearch` but instead will replace `{WSearch}` with Manual+Search.

I hope it can help you or other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are various tips on previewing files in your browser from Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X.
[Preview current HTML file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preview_current_HTML_file)

> This mapping allows you to use a browser to preview the HTML file
>   currently being edited.
>
> ```
>  nnoremap <F5> :silent update<Bar>silent !firefox %:p &<CR>
> ```
>
> If
>   necessary, the current file is saved, then Firefox is used to open the
>   file. Replace "firefox" with the name of another browser if wanted,
>   such as "chromium-browser".

So as the question states that Chrome is the desired browser, then add this to your vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F5> :silent update<Bar>silent !google-chrome %:p &<CR>
```

As well as answer the OP, I wanted to share this link for those that reached this question in search of Windows and Mac OS X support.

Answer (score 1):

For windows 7 or 10 put this line into your .vimrc file:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5> :!start file://C:/Users/<your username here>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %:p<CR>
```

or try:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5> :!start file://C:/Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %:p<CR>
```

for more details see this link:
[Preview current HTML file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preview_current_HTML_file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, you can use `sensible-browser` to open the webpage with your default browser:

```
:!sensible-browser %
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone just now stumbling upon this, you can map this like so in your config files (like `.vimrc`)

```
function OpenInFirefox()
    !firefox % && echo 'File Opened in Firefox'
endfunction

"Open the current file on firefox
command Firefox :call OpenInFirefox()
```

Just replace "firefox" with your browser of choice, then `:Firefox` (or any other custom name you pick) will open the current file in your browser along with a message in your terminal.