# how to edit the _wimrc to open html file with firefox in vim?

Tags: vi

I am learning html, want to edit a html file in vim ,
when i finished the html file,  press <kbd>F4</kbd> to run it with firefox or chrome,
how can i write a line in my _vimrc configuration file to do so ?
in my _vimrc :

```
:map <F4> :w !c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe<cr>   
:map <F5> :w !firefox<cr>
```

i have set my environment path
c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
neither of them can run ,i got `can't find command`.

when i revise the configuration line into :

```
:map <F4> :w !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"<cr>
```

pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> can make firefox open ,but the firefox don't open my current editing html file.

```
  "c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"    file:\\c:\workspace\test.html
```

can open the test.html  ,how can i set it in my _vimrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using vi(m) in the console, this will work but you will have to hit enter once to get back to the html document within the editor:

```
nnoremap <F4> :exe '!"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %'<CR>
```

If you are using gvim, this will avoid having to hit enter that extra time:

```
nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %'<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping:

```
:map <F4> :w !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"<cr>
```

translates to (english): "write the content of this file to the stdin of this firefox program" which is most likely not what you wanted to do here.

What you want to do is:

1. Save the current file.
2. Run firefox with the name of the current file as its argument.

The path to firefox and the file name must both be `shellescape()`ed to deal with the possible spaces in the path names.

This mapping should do what you want:

```
:map <F4> :w\|exec '!' shellescape("c:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe") shellescape(expand(%))<cr>
```

Comment: no :wq, i don't want to save it ,just want to make the current html file run .

Comment: In that case you might want to read the answer to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24931/how-to-make-firefox-read-stdin)

Answer (score 1):

The question you are looking for:

[Open current file in web browser in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708154/open-current-file-in-web-browser-in-vim)

This is exactly your issue.