# vim: Filetype-based key-mapping fails

Tags: html, vim, key-bindings

I'm trying to get vim to send an html file to the browser with a function key. There are [examples](http://alisnic.github.io/posts/vim-run-hotkey/) [around](http://alisnic.github.io/posts/vim-run-hotkey/) including here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708154/open-current-file-in-web-browser-in-vim), but none of the variations I tried worked. Finally, just as I write this question, I remove the filetype condition from the code below and it works. So we know where the problem is, although I don't see how. And I still want to want the key to work differently for different types of files.

```
autocmd FileType html noremap <F5> :update<Bar>silent !start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\opera.exe" "file://%:p"<cr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a mapping based on filetype, you should use `noremap <buffer> ...`; otherwise, it will be defined globally, and also be available in non-HTML buffers afterwards.

The mapping itself looks correct; verify that the filetype is indeed properly detected; `:setl ft?` should yield `html`.

Instead of the autocmd, I'd rather use Vim's abstractions and put the file in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim`. This will then also define the mapping for HTML-derived filetypes (like e.g. `htmldjango`, which source the filetype settings). But that's a matter of preference.

Note that there are plugins that can do this (in a more robust and more general way), e.g. [shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3123) for the current buffer and [openbrowser](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3133) for arbitrary URLs.

Comment: Thanks, Ingo. I checked the filetype detection and vim returned "xhtml," which is almost too clever by half. Would using `html.vim` or the shell plugin tell vim to treat xhtml as a subset of html?

Comment: You could use `after/ftplugin/xhtml.vim`, or (with your initial solution) `:autocmd FileType html,xhtml ...`