# From vim, how do I open a html file in my web browser?

Tags: html

I have started using Vim since last month and I am halfway through Vimscript.Ijust want to know how to run my html file and open it in my browser (Edge).

Update: whenever i am writing this-
nnoremap e :exe ':silent !chromium-browser %'
it is showing that chromium-browser is not an internal or external command

Comment: see this link: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708154/open-current-file-in-web-browser-in-vim)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open current file in web browser in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708154/open-current-file-in-web-browser-in-vim)